# How to access current funds?

Tags: pine-script

How do I capture the funds I currently hold during the execution of the strategy.strategy.I can get the initial money through `strategy.initial_capital`, But how do I get subsequent funding changes.

`strategy.initial_capital - strategy.grossloss + strategy.grossprofit - strategy.closedtrades.commission(strategy.closedtrades - 1)`
The calculated amount does not match the manual value calculated by the trade list in the (cn.tradingview.com) policy tester

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strategy.equity` built-in variable for that.

That would be your current equity -that is `(strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit + strategy.openprofit)`.